Venus’ LIP period starts today, can we save the Venusians?

Following this question, let us propose instead that Venus stayed habitable for longer, and a sapient human-like civilisation arose around the same time as our own (and developed technology at a similar rate). We establish some contact with them and vice-versa (from 20th Century onwards), as would be expected.
Volcanic Large Igneous Provinces (LIPs) start erupting all over Venus’ surface today. Both humanity and the Venusians know that this will likely make Venus uninhabitable. The continued resurfacing is going to be throwing Venus’ climate into chaos (and leading to mass extinctions until there’s nothing left, including the Venusians).
Are there any ways modern humanity could possibly save the Venusians from their hellish fate?

Unless there is a portal connecting Venus to Earth, modern mankind is nowhere near powerful enough to save any planet (including our own) from such a catastrophe.

This question needs a few more details. First: how long do we have? If we had a space barge ready to go, it would still take it a year to get there. Can a Venusian survive on Earth? Can they eat Earth food? Do they even have compatible proteins? Overall, this isn't a "can we save them," it's "how many can we save?"

Hell, IMHO why save the Venusians, when we haven't even begun to save ourselves first. With all the pollutants from CO2 emissions and global warming starting to increase our earth rotation on its axis which making our atmospheric pressures increase and produce more heat and storm activity, the real question is how do we escape Earth with our own hides in tact, take it from Marvin the Martian even if we did give the Venusians our own plans for our precious baby the Illudium Q-36 explosive space modulator, those Venusians would just keep on cracking away at it until it blows up in their faces. T

We barely manage to send at most 5 people at once to space and back, with years of development, testing and failures behind the travel.
Even saving 1000 people, practically a small village somewhere on Venus, would take 200 trips, 200 ships, 200 rockets and so on. A population of X billion people would take many more.
With modern technology we are not able to produce that effort with such a short notice.
The best we might do is send thoughts and prayers.

It is so hard and expensive because of safety concerns. If you need to get the job done quickly and risk of loss is acceptable (because millions will die anyway), you can work much more agile and within far worse safety margins. I believe under such conditions much more can be transported. See what happens in a war - far more things are being done than previously imaginable.

I'd like to add that if we knew and are in contact with a civilisation on Venus, our (manned) Space Programs probably would have been developed a lot further and faster than in the real world. Real World Space program developments are mostly hampered by being underfunded because they don't line the pockets of certain people with money. If theres a civilisation to trade with (and interplanetary tourism), it would be a booster to space travel.

@EisGeflüster, my pessimistic gut feeling tells me that if we were in contact with a civilization on Venus, we would be sending nukes and soldiers before taking refugees from there.

I expect that the best that could be done is to save the venusian species.  99.9 something percent of the venusians are toast.
If the venusians were to collect and freeze genetic material, and their equivalent of eggs and sperm, and then launch rockets crewed by and carrying a few mostly juvenile or young fertile females with a few males of similar maturity, then they may be able to survive on Earth and use the wide variety of venusian gametes to have the fertile females give birth to children with a wide genetic diversity.
It's doable to collect and freeze a lot of gametes, and store them in a small volume and mass.  It's doable to launch rockets carrying twenty or so people.  At least for humans, it's doable for fertile females to be implanted with IVF zygotes.
It might even be doable to export some other venusian species in a similar way... smaller species, or at least the juveniles of larger species.
Noah's Ark wasn't an entirely ridiculous concept, if you assume that you also have a wide variety of frozen gametes.

If you go this route, why bother with the males? I would also be concerned about the culture and knowledge, which may be worth saving too.

@MatthieuM. A few males would be included for precisely the reason of culture.  While the venusians may be human-like, they wouldn't be human, and the females would likely need company and support.  As for cultural records, that's just data, and we can presume that with modern-day tech, that's easily transported.

I wouldn't even expect there to be any special need for anything more than a symbolic transmission of cultural information--unless interplanetary radio communications are highly centralized and regulated, tons of it should have already arrived and been archived on Earth out of academic interest long before there was any sign of an impending catastrophe. If both planets have an Internet, there might even be some interoperability between them, with Venusian websites being archived as a matter of course as well as Venusian users contributing content to Earth websites.

Good point about saving more species than just the sapients. It's entirely possible that they couldn't survive long-term without their native food species, which may depend on native pollinator species, which depend on…. On the flip side, we'd have to be careful about unintentionally saved species, namely pathogens. They could kill enough of those rescued to render the effort in vain, or worse, adapt to Earth species. Got to watch out for those Venereal diseases.

How fast would the Volcanic Large Igneous Provinces take to start up and get going full speed?  Days, weeks, months, years, decades, centuries, millennia, tens of millennia, hundreds of millennia, millions of years, tens of millions of years?
A frame challenge.
I have the impression that a major phase in the geologic history of a planet usually takes millions of years.
So when the Venusian and Earth geologists decide recent geologic events on Venus prove that Volcanic Large Igneous Provinces are starting up and that they will last for say, ten million years and will make Venus uninhabitable in a million years or even a hundred thousand years.
That means that Earth and Venus will have a hundred thousand or maybe even a million years to advance their science and technology and find ways to save the Venusians.  For example, if the Venusians decree a single child per family rule, the number of people in each generation will be half a great as in the previous generation.
After ten generations the 10th generation will have 0.0009765 (1/1024) as many people as the first generation.  A population of a billion in the first generation can be reduced to a population of a million in the 10th generation, and a population of a billion in the first generation could be reduced to a thousand people in the 20th generation.
Suppose in a century or two Earth & Venus are advanced enough to mine asteroids to build artificial space habitats.  And then the first space habitat large enough to for 10,000 to live in is built.  And every time a space habitat is built people move into it to work in outer space building more space habitats, and so the number of space habitats doubles every 50 years.
There will be 2 after 100 years, 4 after 150 years, 8 after 200 years, 16 after 250 years, 32 after 300 years, 64 after 350 years, 128 after 400 years, 256 after 450 years, 512 after 500 years, and 1,024 after 550 years. With room for 10,000 people per habitat, there will now be room for 10,240,000 people.
After another 500 years there would be 1,048,576 habitats with room for 10,485,760,000 people.  After 1,500 years of space habitat construction there would be 1,073,741,824 space habitats with room for 10,727,418,240,000, or ten trillion people, if the population of humans and Venusians has increased that much.
And no doubt there would be much that human and Venusian technology decades, centuries, and millennia more advanced than now could do the fight the geological and climate changes on Venus.
So unless someone can point to calculations which show that Volcanic Large Igneous Provinces can wipe out life on a world in a mere decade or century, it seems probable that the advancing science and technology of Earth and Venus should make it possible for the Venusians to survive.

I would note that while yes population can be reduced at an incredible rate -- if everyone follows through -- expecting to maintain & develop technology with such a small population is by today's standards a pipe dream. There's only so much a single individual can know, there's only so much a single individual can dream, there's only so much a single individual can do in a day. Even at 1 million, I wouldn't bet on the Venusians being able to build out space habitats.

@Matthieu  I mention those as two possible strategies which might be used.  I also note that if the human population does not shrink, the humans should be able to progress and advance their space technology and be able to start building space habitats.

I can't argue with @L.Dutch's answer (which I up voted). Moving an arbitrary number of people in a developed civilization of billions can't be done.
But that's unbelievably boring and I'm not an advocate of the current "as realistic as possible" fad.
First, landing is a lot easier than launching
Which means that Earth isn't sending ships to the surface of Venus, right? So let's examine that for a moment. Earth and Venus send shuttle-style vessels into Venusian orbit. Big ones! After all, a Saturn V rocket is longer than a 747 jet, so it's believable that boosters the size of Saturn Vs can put a 747-sized shuttle into space. Once there, it's just time and some (OK, a lot) of fuel to put the 747 into Venusian orbit. So, let's say 600 people per shuttle for Venus-to-Earth transport and a whole lot of really cheap seats-in-a tube launches to get those 600-per-shuttle into orbit. Keep everything going in rotation until you've saved the Venusians. How many can you save? As many as wanting... so long as you can rationalize time and resource allocation to build the ships and fly them through so much space. Hohmann transfer orbits will not be your friend.
Of course, there are some problems here...
The small ones are...

Time. How fast are those LIPs occuring? If they're geologically slow, you have all the time in the world. If Venus is dead in a year, everybody's hosed. Let's ignore time.

Economics & resources. You need money, people, raw-to-processed-to-manufactured goods, factories... Saving all those people would be a whomping investment. It's one the Venusians would believably pay at any cost because, hey, they're dead if they don't. But the Terrans? Let's ignore this, too.


Then there's the big one...

Immigration! We're not talking about thousands of people entering your country each year, we're talking about more-or-less doubling the population of Earth (assuming 100% success). That is NOT a trivial choice! If the plan had decades (really, decades) to store food, clothing, medical supplies, create housing, etc., etc., etc., then maybe. Maybe. But knowing humans, there would be a fair number of people arguing that all those immigrants would be a bad choice. Right or wrong (depending on what you're trying to sell in your story), they'd be arguing. Some peacefully. Some violently. Either way, maybe we can't ignore time, economics and resources after all.

But let's ignore all of that!
So there's enough time, enough money, enough resources... and you can convince Earth's population to not go bat-ballistic over the whole idea. the advent of the LIPs is detected well enough in advance to allow Earth to economically and sociopolitically prepare for all the people you (yeah, you) want to save. As many 747s are put into orbit by both Venus and Earth and begin shuttling people in rotation to a space station above Earth, which is constantly supplied with everything needed to receive and land the refugees. And above all, the LIPs happen slow enough that everyone you want to save can be. Do we have the tech to do that? Frankly, I think it would make a believable story.
But, now that I think about it, this might be a story-based question
How many people are you trying to save? How much time do you have to save them? Can you get multiple nations to work together to get the job done? There isn't a definitive, "science says this..." answer to any of those questions. Humanity has proven itself perfectly capable of solving really nasty problems (humanity isn't always willing to do that... but character/organization choices are off-topic). That means only you can answer those questions, which means the basic tech isn't really the problem because once you've answered them, we can help you rationalize your world to make those decisions believable.
But without them, there isn't any science that definitively justifies saving anyone. Remember, as of today, the only non-Earth celestial body we've actually visited is our moon.

Ferrying: No / Very limited.
If you mean with "saving" in the sense of "us" sending spaceships over, loading Venusians on board and ferry them back to earth with today's slightly better-than-Apollo-11-SpaceX-tech-level - the answer would be: No.
Given enough time for research, development, tests (!), mass production and conducting the mission(s) plus high amounts of money and good will (and still high risk of failures): maybe a few of them.
Take them in: Probably.
What we maybe could do is accepting Venusian "Apollo-11 equivalent" space ships come to us, allow them to land/live on earth, help them rescue the landing capsules out of the ocean and built them Venusian-appropriate shelters (with a Venus-atmosphere).
All of them: Certainly No.
They are probably also not able to build ships for every single Venusian. And we/earth are probably not able to provide enough support for all of them. There has to be some kind of selection process taking place to make that plausible.

The vast majority of Venusians will die, but I think answers suggesting the entire species is doomed are too pessimistic, for the following reasons.

Our space programs in real life are so slow to develop because we are very adverse to spending money just to explore barren rocks, and if even one astronaut dies it's considered a horrible, irresponsible tragedy.  I don't think either of these would be true in the "Save Venus" scenario.  Saving an similarly-intelligent species from certain death seems like it would be easier to argue for funding, and the safety concerns diminish a lot when there's a whole species at risk if we move too slow.

The question states Venusian society is similarly-advanced to ours.  So they can build rockets too.  Maybe they just build launch vehicles to send refugees up to a space station in low Venus orbit, where they're picked up by a ferry we've sent to ship them back to Earth.  The details aren't that important for this answer; the point is it's not just Earth working on the problem.  And I assume the Venusians work on it sparing basically no expense.

I would expect that, even before the volcanism problem became apparent, that simply knowing there was intelligent life on Venus would drastically speed up space exploration; we would be so eager to meet them in person the space race would have been about sending a person to Venus, not the Moon.  So I think we'd have a head start on the "Save the Venusians" program.



Yes, but not in their current form.
Venus' atmosphere could be reproduced on a small scale, but it's hot (464C, 867F), high pressure (96 Barr) and very, very corrosive (CO2 atmosphere with sulphuric acid rain).
It would be prohibitively expensive to maintain over any time period that would effectively be permanent for large numbers. Many nations could contribute, but what nation would underwrite the cost of the nations that fail to pay-up?
A proposed solution:
Convince the Venusians that their cultural and historical legacies will be fully honored. They part with their entire databases, all their knowledge. Get them to send a single, or series of rockets with as much raw genetic material, tissues and possibly cadavers, maybe volunteers to test (or condemned prisoners - depends on their culture).
Earth-scientists will work together with Venusians to analyze the Venusian and human genomes to find commonalities and differences. A project would run to graft those differences into a viable lifeform for Earth's current conditions - we would remake the Venusians in our own (biochemical) image, able to eat Earth food, breath our air and their skin and immune-systems would cope with our bacteria, viruses, fungi, bugs and parasites and be able to reproduce with humans.
Childless women, and the poor would be incentivized to act as birth-mothers - in very large numbers.
The children of this form (alongside natural-born humans at school) would all be taught about both cultures, raised in the traditions of Earth, but taught how it all was on the other world.
There would be the natural bullying of the different, the segregation of people into work that their particular characteristics would mean they might be best at - and the socio-political reaction to this - leading to smooth and faultless integration (people hope), avoiding all-out species war.
Alternatively.....
This would work especially well on a hive-species:
Having promised all this to the Venusian Queen and labored through the gene-work and solved incompatible biochemistry tangles, we could then enslave them.
The majority could be given guts to deal with general waste, the non-compostable parts that is.
Their brains would be fitted with invasive radio-control (no battery needed - biochemical power at hand) inspired by the work of B.F. Skinner, training them and maintaining control would then be easy. Every family would have one (or more) for basic housework and any more complex tasks they can cope with learning - their loyalty would be assured, digitally.
Specialist jobs such as undersea welder might acquire accessory-gills and be facultative water-breathers - and tolerance for cold (not to mention flippers/fins). The resources of the deep oceans and those on Antarctica might finally be plundered by suitably adapted miners and well-drillers. The resurgence of the dream of human ascendancy to the greatest civilization in the galaxy would arrive - all bourne aloft by the planet of love's gift.

I think the implication of the question was that the OP's venus is not our greenhouse Venus, but rather more earth-like, and the LIP event is going to turn it into our uninhabitable Venus.

@MontyWild exactly

I got that wrong then. Perhaps in future the OP could be specific, as the Venus they refer to isn't the Venus we know, so they should tell us about what their Venus is like. @casualworldbuilder

@Escapeddentalpatient. "let us propose instead that Venus stayed habitable for longer" - I think OP did exactly that.

@zovits Habitable to Venusians, that doesn't tell me anything as the OP didn't describe their physiology/biochemistry nor the environment. If you're going to say "but Venus is therefore Earthlike" - where does it say that? It's not as if there's an established consensus that Venus was like our current Earth. Really the OP needs to state the relevant conditions explicitly in the body of the question, that's how the site works.

@casualworldbuilder I linked a previous question that I asked in which I share a link describing Venus when it may have been habitable: it has liquid surface water oceans, a Nitrogen-rich atmosphere and temperatures averaging between 20-30°C

Nowhere in the question does it mention evacuating Venus to space, I'm not sure why all the answers are focused on that. Instead, assuming Venus has a few decades, humanity's goal should be to slow down their climate change so they can move to airship colonies in the upper atmosphere (see NASA's HAVOC project), and over the proceeding centuries to space; if they can't stop it altogether. Significant research has already been done into sunshades- a runaway greenhouse effect can't happen if there isn't enough heat to trap.
Sunshades are huge endeavors, but the more light you block, you more time you buy, so there is a positive feedback loop. For Earth, only a small percentage of sunlight would need to be blocked to stop climate change, but the LIPs will have a much more drastic effect on the Venusian climate.
Assuming that Venus will eventually reach a greenhouse effect coefficient of 200 (its current value), the required bond albedo to remain habitable would be 99%. However, it would be uninhabitable at that point, regardless of temperature, due to pressure and air composition. You didn't define in your question how quickly the LIP would occur, or the precise mechanism of Venus' transformation to its real life state (which scientists do not know either).
Its unknown what the GH coefficient was when Venus' oceans started to boil, beginning its runaway feedback loop. From some fiddling around with this calculator, assuming original Venus has the same albedo as Earth, you would need to deflect about 25% of the incoming sunlight to prevent the oceans from boiling.
A total sunshade at Venus's L1 point would need to be 12,870 in diameter, an area of 130 million square kilometers, a 25% one would have a an area of 33 million. Using a 20 nanometer layer of beryllium, the lightest solar sail material known, an area density of .02 g/m^2 could be achieved, resulting in a mass of 660,000 tons. You would want a swarm of cubesats, which would sail from Low Earth Orbit to Venus and use solar radiation to stabilize themselves at the Venus-Sun L1 (read about Statites for more information). Currently, humanity only launches 1200 tons a year into space, but 1. We are less than a decade away from superheavy, reusable rockets such as the Long March 9 and Starship. 2. In a timeline where we came in contact with a civilization on Venus, we would presumably have started developing such rockets sooner, and funded space exploration more extensively. With 10 rapidly reusable Starship sized vehicles, you could deliver 200 tons * 1 launch a week * 10 = 100,000 tons a year.
You can save on launch costs by mining the conveniently located asteroid, 2002VE, which is a quasi-moon of Venus.
TLDR: As long as Venus has a few decades, we can stop their oceans from boiling by blocking sunlight. Convincing humanity to embark on an urgent, expensive, herculean feat to do so might be a good source of conflict for your story.
